# How to insert and update data from CSV using sqlcmd on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I can convert data database to `.csv` using `sqlcmd` syntax on my ubuntu

```
sqlcmd -S ipdb -U sa -P "passwordsa" -d dbname -Q "select * from tabelname" -o "direktori/file.csv" -s"," -W -w 700
```

but how can I insert data from my `.csv` to table using `sqlcmd` syntax?

Comment: @matigo yes, can you help me?

Comment: I cannot try it, but as a hint I would try something like `sqlcmd -S ipdb -U sa -P "passwordsa" -d dbname -Q "BULK INSERT tabelname FROM 'direktori/file.csv' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', TABLOCK)"`. More details about "bulk insert" on official website : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks you @FloT
And I read to know more about bulk insert, and I find this link 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-bcp?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Great ! May I suggest you to answer your own question and mark it as solved then ?

Comment: okay, but I dont know how to mark it as solved. Could you please show me the way? @FloT

Comment: There should be an "Answer your question" button somewhere below the question. Click it, add your solution and save it. Then I guess you'll be able to accept your answer by clicking on the tick below the upvote / downvote buttons. You can refer to this post : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @FloT okay thankyou very much. Have A nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved by using bulk copy data (bcp) syntax.

```
bcp Tablename in ~/filename.txt -S localhost -U sa -P <your_password> -d Databasename -c -t  ','
```